# Gradle Jar type task doesn't package .class files from src/main

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I defined a task "exeJar" with Jar type to package an executable jar, shown as below.

```
task exeJar(type: Jar, group: 'build', dependsOn: classes) {

    description 'Package an executable jar.'

    archiveClassifier.set('exe')

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

}
```

And I make the jar task exclude the main class.

```
jar{
    exclude 'com/example/*class'
}
```

jar: packages an `artifactId-version.jar` file containing only the resources from `src/main` and excluding the main class.

exeJar: packages an executable `artifactId-version-exe.jar` file.

But the `artifactId-version-exe.jar` only contains the dependencies and excludes the resources from `src/main` directory, shown in the picture below.

[image: the contents of .jar]

Can someone explain why this happens and give a possible solution to make `artifactId-version-exe.jar` contain the main class?

Comment: It should be runtimeClasspath, not runtime. runtime is deprecated for a long time. Stop using it.

Comment: Find an answer here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/sourcesets-main-compileclasspath-vs-configurations-compile/6782.
I should add the main output of "sourceSets" task. The code like this:
`from { (configurations.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.main.output).collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }`